# Port 9000 not listed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi, hhvm, puphpet

I am using puphpet with ubuntu/nginx/hhvm.

Everything works well until I restart the virtual machine. After vagrant reload or halt/up I get a 502 error.
I notice that after one of mentioned actions the port 9000 is not listed.
I have to restart the hhvm service to get the port started.

How can i make this port (9000) to be listed at virtual machine start?

Comment: Can you share your configuration? Thanks

Comment: I "hacked" the problem creating a bash script that restart the hhvm service everytime the vm is starting. I can't share any config file because i gave up using this environment because I could not send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HHVM getting started wiki page](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Getting-Started) indicates the likely solution to this. (I think it's also printed on the console when you `apt-get install hhvm`):

```
sudo update-rc.d hhvm defaults
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! I missed that part from the docs.